# Datapath of a file in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am building R shiny app which deals with finding optimal model for the data given.
I want to add a save option where i copy all the choices which the user made including the datapath of the file he has uploaded in a list and then use it's contents the next time the user opens the app.
The problem with datapath is that it changes each time the user upload the data (the same file):
That's a print of the datapath of the same file in two different times:

```
"datapath"
[1] "C:\\Users\\Myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpy6GGSi/a71248f0a76cf0ebf939a877/0"

"datapath"
[1] "C:\\Users\\Myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpy6GGSi/28332d77d53b9c7c63d5101c/0"
```

When I want to read the file using the saved `file$datapath` i get an error which tells me that such a file does not exist.

Is there any way to set the last part of the datapath (`a71248f0a76cf0ebf939a877`) as constant or any other hint which can help me?

Comment: `datapath` is the temporary location where the uploaded file is saved. You can use `file.copy` to copy the file to a fixed location so that it can be used next time.